# npm config set registry <registry url> - can we use registry to point to local node_modules folder

Tags: node.js

npm config set registry  - can we use registry to point to local node_modules folder i.e node_modules on filesytem instead of a url.
I have all required artifacts under node_modules local to my application. When I deploy over private cloud it fails as it tries to download node oracledb binary.

Answer (score 0):

No is not for that. 
That option was used some time ago to use another registry different from the official npm registry. Mostly enterprise installations needs their own private registry. This option was very useful, rigth now Im not sure if it is used or it was deprecated due the new infra of npm

To solve the installation of oracledb you'll need build tools installed on the server  so `npm install` could compile binaries.